# Android: Sending a Bitmap to PHP server crashes the app

Tags: php, android, bitmap

I want to send an image to the server by converting it to string. 
Here is my code for conversion:

```
public String baseTo64 (Bitmap bitmapImage){
        String imageString = null;
            try {

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); 
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                imageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

     return imageString;
}
```

I use AyncTask to send the string along with other strings.

```
class SubmitReport extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String image = baseTo64(bitmapImage);
            String desc =  text2.getText().toString();
            r.setType(rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
            String type = r.getType();
            String latitude = String.valueOf(r.getLati());
            String longitude = String.valueOf(r.getLongi());
            String dateH = r.getStringDate();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("desc", desc));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateH", dateH));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_submit_report, "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // success

                    Log.d("SUCCESS", json.toString());

                    // closing this screen
                   // finish();
                } else {
                    // failed
                    Log.d("FAILED", json.toString());

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


    }
```

My app can successfully send data to server without including the image. 
 But if I call baseTo64 inside the AsynTask, it crashes.
Is this because of too much memory used? I think the returned string is so large to be sent to the server because when I try to use baseTo64 method and display it via toast with only its first 5 characters, it did display the characters. 
 
If that's the case, what will I do to prevent/avoid this? Please help.

```
07-24 13:32:47.836  26033-27529/com.example.jay.curloc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
    Process: com.example.jay.curloc, PID: 26033
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.jay.curloc.ReportIncident$SubmitReport.doInBackground(ReportIncident.java:455)
            at com.example.jay.curloc.ReportIncident$SubmitReport.doInBackground(ReportIncident.java:417)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Add your logcat please

Comment: Your baseTo64 function should not even compile as it does not return a value in case of a catch. Let it return null then. And check in doInBackgroud if it returned null and do not continue if it does.

Comment: @greenapps sorry.. I already edited my baseTo64 function. 
I don't know but if I only get the first 100 characters of the returned string, it does not crash.

Comment: `I already edited my baseTo64 function.`. I see. But you are not checking for null in doInBackground().  `I only get the first 100 characters of the returned string,`. WHERE do you get ? You have a NullPointerException! Did you solve that already? On which codeline is that?

Comment: I tried to make the returned string like this : `return imageString.substring(0,100)` . My app did not crash and I check my database and it was there. But if I only do `return imageString`, it throws a nullpointer exception on `java:455` line which is  `Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());`

Comment: So json is null then. You shoud also check for json==null and not continue is it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Add null check like bellow code .

```
if(fileUri!=null)
{

     // do all relevant part here. 
}
```

Comment: I don't know but if I only save the first 100 characters of the string, it does not crash.